# create a dictionary to map enums to events

Tags: asp.net, events, dictionary, delegates

I'm trying to create a dictionary to map an enum to a set of events with the same signature . I wrote :

```
public enum Events {Insert, Update, Delete};

// this part makes errors
Dictionary<Events,EventHandler<T>> EventsDic = new Dictionary<Events,EventHandler<T>>()
{
     { Events.Insert , this.ItemInserted}
};
```

what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `T` has to be replaced with a type since you are declaring a variable. `T` must be the type of the `value` in the dictionary or, in your specific case, the type of the event arguments. Since you specifically say you are wanting to store events, `T` should probably be the good old `EventArgs`. Your code should look something like this:

```
Dictionary<Events,EventHandler<EventArgs>> EventsDic = new Dictionary<Events,EventHandler<EventArgs>>()
{
     { Events.Insert , this.ItemInserted}
};
```